# Solr's [child] Document Transformer returning empty child fields

Tags: solr, solrj, spring-data-solr, solr8

I am trying to return child document fields with the parent in a query's field list.

In version 7.7 of Solr, we had to specify `fl=*,[child parentFilter=type:account]` which would correctly return all parents' fields along with the associated child documents of type `account`.

In version 8.x of Solr, things changed with the introduction of `_nest_path_`. We are properly including both the fieldType `_nest_path_` and the field `_nest_path_` in the schema (it's generated by SolrJ).

```
<fieldType name="_nest_path_" class="solr.NestPathField" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" omitNorms="true" maxCharsForDocValues="-1" stored="false"/>
<field name="_nest_path_" type="_nest_path_"/>
```

We are able to properly query on child document fields in relation to the parent, but unable to return child document fields.

In my example, I have two parent documents (account), each with 3 child documents (policy).

Here is the flat structure returned by `*:*`

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":25,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1611069992439"}},
  "response":{"numFound":8,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"policy-1",
        "type":["policy"],
        "_version_":1689330740566687744},
      {
        "id":"policy-2",
        "type":["policy"],
        "_version_":1689330740566687744},
      {
        "id":"policy-3",
        "type":["policy"],
        "_version_":1689330740566687744},
      {
        "id":"account-1",
        "name":["Harvey John Birdman"],
        "type":["account"],
        "_version_":1689330740566687744},
      {
        "id":"policy-4",
        "type":["policy"],
        "_version_":1689330740571930624},
      {
        "id":"policy-5",
        "type":["policy"],
        "_version_":1689330740571930624},
      {
        "id":"policy-6",
        "type":["policy"],
        "_version_":1689330740571930624},
      {
        "id":"account-2",
        "name":["Billy George Zane"],
        "type":["account"],
        "_version_":1689330740571930624}]
  }}
```

Here is the response for `q=type:account&fl=*,[child]`

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":28,
    "params":{
      "q":"type:account",
      "fl":"*,[child]",
      "_":"1611069992439"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"maxScore":0.5822426,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"account-1",
        "name":["Harvey John Birdman"],
        "type":["account"],
        "_version_":1689330740566687744},
      {
        "id":"account-2",
        "name":["Billy George Zane"],
        "type":["account"],
        "_version_":1689330740571930624}]
  }}
```

And if I don't return any parent fields, I get empty results (no child data)

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":29,
    "params":{
      "q":"type:account",
      "fl":"[child]",
      "_":"1611069992439"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"maxScore":0.5822426,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {},
      {}]
  }}
```

I am using Spring's abstraction on SolrJ, but using SolrJ direct with the `SolrInputDocument` results in the same thing. Mentioning this in case there are any known bugs with either of these libraries.

Solr version = 8.5.2

SolrJ version = 8.5.2